# Does WinSCP .NET assembly support implicit TLS/SSL with client certificate authentication for FTPS?

Tags: ssl, ftp, client-certificates, winscp, winscp-net

Windows WinSCP application version 5.8.1 beta seems to support TLS/SSL client certificate authentication with implicit TLS/SSL for FTP.

I wonder if WinSCP .NET assembly (dll version of WinSCP) supports this type of authentication?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.

Use the [`SessionOptions.TlsClientCertificatePath`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#tlsclientcertificatepath) to specify a full path to [TLS/SSL client certificate](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tls#client_certificate).